# Gradle build with Lombok

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

I am trying to develop a web application with `SpringBoot` and `Lombok` to reduce boilerplate code.

While the annotated class works fine, I am getting compilation errors in target classes.

I am not trying to compile via IDE but directly via commandline using gradlew build.

Any suggestion on how to integrate `Lombok` with `gradle` to build and generate jars will be really helpful.

Git repository: https://github.com/ashubisht/sample-sbs.git

The error I am getting is:

```
 \sample-sbs\src\main\java\com\sample\springboot\Controllers\RestControllerClass.java:28:
 error: constructor Customer in class Customer cannot be applied to given types;

 customerDAO.insert(new Customer(1, "Utkarsh", 25));
                               ^
 required: no arguments
 found: int,String,int
 reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
 1 error
```

Customer class is annotated with @Data annotation.

Comment: I know this url. I am able to add gradle plugin. The dependencies are present in gradle libraries. I can get java imports for @Data. Its the target classes where error is coming. I want to verify gradle build dont produce any compilation error.

Comment: To be honest, I have no clue what is your problem. *I am getting compilation errors in target classes.* what kind of errors, and what you you mean by *target classes*. You also write that you got lombok configured and it works - but it don't work. If you follow guidence from provided link, app will compile just fine.

Comment: From command line, when I do gradlew build, it gives me compilation error on classes where I use getter methods or constructor of the classes annotated with @Data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your [`Customer`](https://github.com/ashubisht/sample-sbs/blob/master/src/main/java/com/sample/springboot/schema/Customer.java) class, all the fields that you're trying to initialize in the constructor are non-final.

Since [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) annotation adds only [`@RequiredArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), you cannot initialize non-final fields in the constructor without explicitly annotating this class with [`@AllArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor).

So you either need to annotate the class with [`@AllArgsConstructor`](https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor), or use setters to initialize the object.

Answer (score 0):

In the current lombok release 1.18.0 there is [an issue with Gradle 4.9](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/1782), which will be fixed in the upcoming lombok release 1.18.2.

If you are using Gradle 4.9, either downgrade Gradle, wait for lombok 1.18.2, or use the [current lombok edge release](https://projectlombok.org/download-edge).

Comment: But the OP's code runs on [Gradle 4.4](https://github.com/ashubisht/sample-sbs/blob/master/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties)

Comment: Oh, indeed :)
Well, we really need more information, then. The exact error message would be nice...

Comment: I have added error message. It seems like I have to add something more than just dependencies. Do I need to add some task instead of using default gradle build?